# Mocked method not called in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Hello I have one service with a method:

```
@Service
public class CaptchaServiceImpl implements CaptchaService {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public boolean processCaptcha(String requestedUrl, String challenge, String userResponse) {

    ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
    reCaptcha.setPrivateKey(messageSource.getMessage("reCaptcha.private.key", new Object[]{}, new Locale("pl", "PL")));
    ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(requestedUrl, challenge, userResponse);

    return reCaptchaResponse.isValid();
}
```

}

and I wrote a test for it:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CaptchaServiceImplTest {

private CaptchaService captchaService;

@Mock
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Mock
private ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha;

@Before
public void init() {
    captchaService = new CaptchaServiceImpl();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(captchaService, "messageSource", messageSource);
}

@Test
public void shouldPassReCaptchaValidation() {
    ReCaptchaTestResponse captchaResponse = new ReCaptchaTestResponse(true, "no errors");
    when(messageSource.getMessage("reCaptcha.private.key", new Object[]{}, new Locale("pl", "PL"))).thenReturn("reCaptcha.private.key");
    when(reCaptcha.checkAnswer(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(captchaResponse);

    boolean reCaptchaResponse = captchaService.processCaptcha("url", "challenger", "userResponse");

    assertThat(reCaptchaResponse, is(true));
}

private class ReCaptchaTestResponse extends ReCaptchaResponse {

    protected ReCaptchaTestResponse(boolean valid, String errorMessage) {
        super(valid, errorMessage);
    }
}
```

}

ReCaptchaResponse is protected class...

So when I run my test I am getting:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: 
 Expected: is <true>
 got: <false>
```

For some reason my mocked method checkAnswer is never called and my captchaResponse object is never returned and I have ran out of ideas why. Could someone tell my why it is happening? Maybe I am missing something :/

UPDATE:

So I have updated my CaptchaService:

```
@Autowired
private ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha;

@Override
public boolean processCaptcha(String requestedUrl, String challenge, String userResponse) {
    reCaptcha.setPrivateKey(messageSource.getMessage("reCaptcha.private.key", new Object[]{}, new Locale("pl", "PL")));
    ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(requestedUrl, challenge, userResponse);

    return reCaptchaResponse.isValid();
}
```

and now test is green! :) Thanks

Comment: Are you using FEST? `assertThat(reCaptchaResponse, is(true));` doesn't look right - I _think_ that should be `assertThat(reCaptchaResponse).isTrue();`

Comment: what does FEST stand for?

Comment: It's a testing library. https://code.google.com/p/fest/

Comment: No, I'm using hamcrest. I wasn't familiar with FEST, thanks for the link.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm less familiar with hamcrest. Check out FEST; I find its DSL more English-like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
```

That's just creating a new instance - your mock isn't being used at all. Note how you're not passing your mock into anything - how did you expect the production code to use it?

Mocks are good for injected dependencies, or even dependencies which are returned by a factory where you can make the factory return the mock for you - but you're just calling the constructor.

You *could* use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) for this, but I'd suggest redesigning either to avoid needing the mock at all, or to allow the dependency to be injected somewhere.

Comment: You are right, I have to configure a ReCaptchaImpl bean in Spring for that. I thought that there can be a problem with it.. just got an eclipse. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: You should put in bold **redesigning** ;)